# Problem merging 30min dataframes - midnight data goes missing

Tags: r, merge, timestamp

I have several csv files that I want to merge together to make a continuous dataset. My acquisition system generates a row of data (23 variables) every 30min and each csv file covers 24hrs. The first step is to create a dataframe (dataMerge) by merging all the files together based the TIMESTAMP column (col1). This works fine. In the second step, I create a dataframe (df) that has 30min TIMESTAMP for the entire year (17521 obs. of 1 variable). What I want to do next is to merge df and dataMerge together in order to get a dataframe for the entire year, even for periods where data is missing.

As I mentionned above the first merge works fine. However, when I try to merge df and dataMerge, the resulting dataframe (AllMerge) is missing data in every midnight rows.

[image]

```
FileNames <- list.files(path = path_load)
headers <- read.csv(file = paste(path_load, FileNames[1], sep=""), skip = 1, header = F, nrows = 1, as.is = T)

FirstFile <- read.csv(file = paste(path_load, FileNames[1], sep=""), skip = 4, header = F)
colnames(FirstFile) = headers

SecondFile <- read.csv(file = paste(path_load, FileNames[2], sep=""), skip = 4, header = F)
colnames(SecondFile) = headers

dataMerge <- merge(FirstFile, SecondFile, all = T)

for(i in 3:length(FileNames)){
  ReadInMerge <- read.csv(file=paste(path_load, FileNames[i], sep=""), skip = 4, header = F)
  colnames(ReadInMerge) = headers
  dataMerge <- merge(dataMerge, ReadInMerge, all=T)
}

df <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP = seq(as.POSIXct("2024-01-01", tz = "EST"),
                                as.POSIXct("2024-12-31", tz = "EST"),
                                by=(30*60)))

AllMerge <- merge(df, dataMerge, all.x = T, by = "TIMESTAMP")
```

I have tried

```
AllMerge <- merge(df, dataMerge, all = T, by = "TIMESTAMP")
```

but I get two rows for midnight, one with, and one without data.
Two rows 2024-02-14 00:00:00:

[image]

Edit: The problem was with the format of the timestamp column in the csv files. This code works perfectly now:

```
FileNames <- list.files(path = path_load)
headers <- read.csv(file = paste(path_load, FileNames[1], sep=""), skip = 1, header = F, nrows = 1, as.is = T)

FirstFile <- read.csv(file = paste(path_load, FileNames[1], sep=""), skip = 4, header = F)
colnames(FirstFile) = headers
FirstFile$TIMESTAMP <- as.POSIXct(FirstFile$TIMESTAMP,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

SecondFile <- read.csv(file = paste(path_load, FileNames[2], sep=""), skip = 4, header = F)
colnames(SecondFile) = headers
SecondFile$TIMESTAMP <- as.POSIXct(SecondFile$TIMESTAMP,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

dataMerge <- merge(FirstFile, SecondFile, all = T)

for(i in 3:length(FileNames)){
  ReadInMerge <- read.csv(file=paste(path_load, FileNames[i], sep=""), skip = 4, header = F)
  colnames(ReadInMerge) = headers
  ReadInMerge$TIMESTAMP <- as.POSIXct(ReadInMerge$TIMESTAMP,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  dataMerge <- merge(dataMerge, ReadInMerge, all=T)
}

df <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP = seq(as.POSIXct("2024-01-01", tz = "EST"),
                                as.POSIXct("2024-12-31", tz = "EST"),
                                by=(30*60)))



AllMerge <- merge(df, dataMerge, all.x = T, by = "TIMESTAMP")
```

Comment: Please do not provide pictures of data. Rather run `dput(mydata)` and share its output.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. See edit above, I found the problem while learning how to use dput(mydata) watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rn6BgT15yIs